# Java : How to create map using the class attributes?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a map from all the attributes that a class have.My class looks like :

```
public class MyInventory
{
   private int tiers = 80;
   private int stearing =135;
   private int battery = 46;

 }
```

Now I have collected all the methods that the class has as :

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

Now , I am trying to create a Map out of it where keys are the values of the fields and the values are the name of the fields. Example :

```
Map<46,battery> ...etc
```

Is there a way to do it?
The attribute values for the above mentioned class were generated by mapping to properties file and by using spring annotation @ConfigurationProperties. Now I need to create the Map but keys the values of the attributes. I tried to use reflect. However did not find a way to get the value of the fields.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create a `Map<int,String>` - what's the issue?

Comment: It sound strange, we often create key by field name not vice versa. Anyway, it's possible. Just use reflect api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

Comment: @BalwinderSingh `Map<Integer, String>` * ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad true. Typed in hurry I suppose ;)

Comment: Why in the world would you need a map if you already have your class done? Wouldn't it be simpler if you work with a list of MyInventory?

Comment: What do you expect if `tiers` and `battery` should both reference the same value (i.e. `5`)? Which field name should be set as the value for the key `5`?

Comment: It's just an example. In my case, they are never going to be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Introspector` class.

```
public Map<Object, String> populateMap(final Object o) throws Exception {
  Map<Object, String> result = new HashMap<>();
  for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    String fieldName = pd.getName();
    if("class".equals(fieldName) continue;
    Object value = pd.getReadMethod().invoke(o);
    result.put(value, fieldName);
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can call the above method, passing your class as argument.

```
MyInventory mi = new MyInventory();
// Sets the properties of mi
mi.setXXX...
// Populates map
populateMap(mi);
```

Comment: I am getting  :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 2):

```
  Map<Integer, String> map() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

       Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
       Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
       for (Field field : fields) {
           map.put(field.getInt(this), field.getName());
       }
       return map;
   }
```

Of course it will not map properly if different fields have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can have getter method in your class

```
public class MyInventory
{
   private int tiers = 80;
   private int stearing =135;
   private int battery = 46;

   public int getBattery()
   {
       return battery;
   }
  //and other getter 
 }
```

and then you can populate your map as

```
map.put(inventory.getBattery(),"battery");
```

Because, when you have value, which means you know what is the type for which you are populating map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json parser. For example jackson:

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
  ... 
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(fooOject), HashMap.class);
```