# How to get object's fields as comma separated string or a list in java

Tags: java, string, list, properties, instance

I am trying to get the object's properties as a list. So for example:

```
class Sample {

  private String type;
  private String name;
  private int value;
  
  // getter-setter
}
```

Expected output:
`{"type", "name", "value"}`

Is there a programmatical way to do this?

Comment: Try referencing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771802/java-how-to-create-map-using-the-class-attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java Reflexion

```java
public static String getClassProperties(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
        .map(field -> "\"" + field.getName() + "\"")
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getClassProperties(Sample.class)); 
}
```

***Output:***

> {"type", "name", "value"}